# Android Gradle not finding remote AAR

Tags: android, gradle, aar

I was working with **Gradle v5.4** and **Android Gradle Plugin v3.5.2**, and had no problems!

I have a remote Artifactory repository where I upload `.aar` files that are needed in my project.

When I updated to **Gradle v6.5** and **Android Gradle Plugin v4.0.1** those `.aar` files are no longer downloaded.

This is how I add those dependencies:

```
implementation "ar.com.sebasira:some-library:1.0.0@aar"
```

This was working just fine before the upgrade.

In the logs I can see that AndroidStudio looks for it in this location:

> https://myrepo.com.ar/ar/com/sebasira/some-library/1.0.0/some-library-1.0.0.pom

If I put that URL in the browser, indeed there's nothing to be found, but if I change the last part (the extension) to `.aar` I can download the artifact.

I thought that adding **@aar** was to instruct Gradle to look for `.aar` file but it seems not to be working.

I've also try adding the dependency like in this other way with no luck.

```
implementation group: 'ar.com.sebasira', name: 'some-library', version: '1.0.0', ext: 'aar'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found out that since **Gradle v6.0** onwards, Gradle assumes that if no `.pom` file is present in the remote repository is because the artifact does not exists, so it does not look for it by default. According to [release notes](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/upgrading_version_5.html?_ga=2.255197579.228643275.1602943892-1233682684.1602943892#maven_or_ivy_repositories_are_no_longer_queried_for_artifacts_without_metadata_by_default):

> If Gradle fails to locate the metadata file (`.pom` or `ivy.xml`) of a module in a repository defined in the `repositories { }` section, it now assumes that the module does not exist in that repository.
>
> ...
>
> You can opt into the old behavior for selected repositories by adding the `artifact()` metadata source.

So the solution is to add that to repository in question, like this:

```
repositories {
    maven {
        url 'the-repo-url'
        metadataSources {
            artifact()
        }
    }
}
```